# Given a Jordan canonical basis, how to find out to which generalized eigenspace picked generalized eigenvector belongs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

Suppose we have finite-dimensional linear operator $A:V\to V$ , that has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 ,\lambda_2, ... \lambda_n$ . It is known that we can decompose $V$ into direct sum of generalized eigenspaces $\Lambda_i$, corresponding to each $\lambda_i$, with respect to $A$.
$$
V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \Lambda_i
$$
Usually we do this decomposition by solving
$$
B_i^kv=0,
$$
i.e finding $ \operatorname{Ker} B^k_i$, where $B^k_i = (A-\lambda_iI)^k$. This is simple and gives us the complete structure of decomposition, that can be visualized as a diagram with arrows showing application of corresponding $B_i$ to basis vectors of each generalized eigenspace until all of them turn into $0$

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    e_5 @>B_1>> e_4 @>B_1>> e_3 @>B_1>>0\\
    \\
    @. e_6 @>B_1>> e_2 @>B_1>>0\\
    \\
    e_8 @>B_2>> e_7 @>B_2>> e_1 @>B_2>>0\\
\end{CD}
In the example above, $V$ is split into two generalized eigenspaces: the first is spanned by $(e_5, e_4, e_3, e_6, e_2)$, and the second is spanned by $(e_8, e_7, e_1)$.
All of this is very good, but is it possible, given a canonical Jordan basis, i.e. set of generalized eigenvectors $(e_i)$, and a set of eigenvalues, to reconstruct which generalized eigenvectors belong to which generalized eigenspace $\Lambda_i$ ? In other words, is it possible to draw arrows in the diagram above, if we don't know them?

It is obvious that we can try each $B_i$ to see which of them sends (after some number of applications) the vector to $0$, but I'm keen if there is other approach, that doesn't require us to do such a bruteforcing.
Every book I had a look at before asking this question doesn't ever mention any problem similar to this, or maybe I haven't read them thoroughly enough.
Sorry if this question is trivial and I just can't see the solution, but I stuck with it really hard.

Comment: The matrix of $A$ on this basis will be in normal form, so you can simply apply $A$ instead. Each vector $v$ will either be sent to $Av = \lambda_i v$ (in which case it is an eigenvector, at the end of the chain), or $Av = \lambda_i v + u$ for some other vector $u$ in the set. So applying $A$, rather than any of the $B_i$, can tell you both $i$ and the next vector in the chain. The only brute-forcey part is checking whether $Av - u$ is proportional to $v$ for all the different $u$. Is this what you're after?